# SQL SELECT from TABLE B based on column but grab all rows based on TABLE A ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, one-to-many

So I've been hit with a dozy this morning.

I've got two tables listed below.

```
TABLE A
InvoiceNo | Total
000001    | $100
000002    | $50
000003    | $200
etc..

TABLE B
InvoiceNo | ItemCode
000001    | Item-A
000001    | Item-B
000001    | Item-C
000002    | Item-A
000003    | Item-B
000003    | Item-D
etc...
```

I need to select out of table 2 where ITEM-B exists, but also grab all other items based on the InvoiceNo.  So it should grab ItemCode > InvoiceNo > All Items based on that InvoiceNo

```
OUTPUT
InvoiceNo | Total | ItemCode
000001    | $100  | Item-A
000001    | $100  | Item-B
000001    | $100  | Item-C
000003    | $200  | Item-B
000003    | $200  | Item-D
```

The query I'm currently working with is:

```
SELECT a.InvoiceNo, a.Total, b.ItemCode FROM TableA a
LEFT JOIN TABLE B b ON a.InvoiceNo = b.InvoiceNo
WHERE b.ItemCode = 'Item-B'
```

This generates the following output

```
INCORRECT OUTPUT
InvoiceNo | Total | ItemCode
000001    | $100  | Item-B
000003    | $200  | Item-B
```

I'm not quite sure how to approach this, any clues or assistance would be very appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. One way is by using `EXISTS`

```
SELECT  a.InvoiceNo, A.Total, B.ItemCode
FROM    TableA a
        INNER JOIN TableB b
            ON a.InvoiceNo = b.InvoiceNo
WHERE   EXISTS (SELECT 1
                FROM TableB c
                WHERE b.InvoiceNo = c.InvoiceNo
                        AND c.ItemCode = 'Item-B')
```

Here's a [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f1bb0/1).

Another way is by using `INNER JOIN` on a subquery which only get all invoices having `ItemB`

```
SELECT  a.InvoiceNo, A.Total, B.ItemCode
FROM    TableA a
        INNER JOIN TableB b
            ON a.InvoiceNo = b.InvoiceNo
        INNER JOIN (SELECT InvoiceNo FROM TableB c WHERE ItemCode = 'Item-B') c
            ON a.InvoiceNo = c.InvoiceNo
```

Here's a [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f1bb0/3).

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be what you're after:

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE TABLEA (InvoiceNo varchar(6),
                     Total int)

CREATE TABLE TABLEB (InvoiceNo varchar(6),
                     ItemCode varchar(6));
GO
INSERT INTO TABLEA
VALUES ('000001',100),
       ('000002',50 ),
       ('000003',200);
INSERT INTO TABLEB
VALUES ('000001','Item-A'),
       ('000001','Item-B'),
       ('000001','Item-C'),
       ('000002','Item-A'),
       ('000003','Item-B'),
       ('000003','Item-D');
GO
SELECT B.InvoiceNo,
       A.Total,
       B.ItemCode
FROM TABLEB B
     JOIN TABLEA A ON B.InvoiceNo = A.InvoiceNo
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1
             FROM TABLEB sq
             WHERE B.InvoiceNo = sq.InvoiceNo
               AND sq.ItemCode = 'Item-B')
ORDER BY B.InvoiceNo, B.ItemCode;

GO
DROP TABLE TABLEA;
DROP TABLE TABLEB;
```